# What can I use to remove caulk from acrylic shower wall seams without damaging the surface shine of new walls?

Tags: shower, caulk, acrylic

I hired someone to install. They used dirty hands to sloppily apply the caulk. It’s all over - clumpy globs of dirty caulk in the seams. And on the shower walls. I need to remove it and do it right. But I don’t want to scratch or remove the shine of the new walls. How do I clean up this mess?

[image]

Comment: use something softer than the walls. a credit card or worst-case rubber spatula is safe; test first on a hidden area.

Comment: A plastic putty knife should do it. There's a caulk softening product called Goo Gone. It might not be compatible with acrylic or whatever that is, do a test if you end up using the stuff.

Comment: Also a steam cleaner is a great way to soften up the caulk and weaken it's holding power.

Comment: If this was just completed, withhold final payment until the installer cleans it up. This is shoddy workmanship and not holding the worker accountable makes her think she's done a fine job and can continue to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need a commercial caulk remover & a plastic scraper.

Example images from Google for "acrylic caulk remover"

[image]